# Set ng-animate to fade in image on page load

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I am trying to get `ng-animate` to fade in an image on page load, but with little success. What am I missing out on?

This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<img class="logo fade-in" 
     src="images/dog.svg" 
     ng-animate="{show:'animate-show', hide:'animate-hide'}">
```

**CSS**

```
.animate-show, .animate-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
  -o-transition:all linear 1s;
  transition:all linear 1s;

}

.animate-show {
  opacity:0;
}

.animate-show.animate-show-active {
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-hide {
  opacity:1;
}

.animate-hide.animate-hide-active {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: AngularJS version?

Comment: @tasseKATT I'm on 1.6.1